# Get Minutes and output them with SendKeys

Tags: powershell, sendkeys, getdate

this is my first time scripting, and I wanted to start small.
My goal is simple: get the current time (Get-Date -Format mm) and output that 2 digit number as keystrokes with SendKeys.

Problem is, I have no idea how to convert that 2 digit output into an object for the "SendKeys" to output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the Datetime results first to String using the `ToString()` Method if you have some problem to send it, here's the full example to send it to notepad:

```
## Find all Active Windows Titles
$windows=Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""} | Select-Object MainWindowTitle
## Find Specific name 
$WindowTitle=($windows | ? {$_ -match "Notepad"} ).MainWindowTitle
## Add Type and Focus Activate the Window
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$wshell.AppActivate($WindowTitle)
## Send Keys
$wshell.SendKeys((Get-Date -Format mm).ToString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the full requirement is here but you could send the minutes to notepad like below

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$secs = Get-Date -Format mm
notepad

start-sleep -Milliseconds 500

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("notepad")

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($secs)
```